# Requiring derived class to define a method

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class

I am no doubt overlooking something basic but my implementation is obviously flawed.

I am trying to require a derived classes to implement a method being called in a base class.

```
class IClock
{
public:
    virtual void OnTimeExpired() = 0;
}

class Clock : public IClock
{
    ... // ABC not implemented
}

class Application : public Clock
{
    ... // ABC not implemented
}

class DerivedApp : public Application
{
public: 
    virtual void OnTimeExpired() { ... }
}
```

I rarely use pure ABCs, so I thought by **not** defining the pure virtual method in `Clock` and `Application`, it would require all derivatives of `Application` to define the `OnTimeExpired()` method.

I discovered this will compile and link (MSVS-2017) **and if `DerivedApp` does not implement the method, the `Clock` object will call an undefined method and crash.**

1. Why does this compile without the pure virtual method being implemented?
2. How do I force derived `Application` classes to implement the `OnTimeExpired()` method?

**EDIT: The crash was due to unrelated error - I apologize. Nevertheless the questions I ask are still applicable.**

As requested here is a complete, buildable, minimal example:

IClock.h:

```
#pragma once

class IClock
{
public:
    virtual void OnClockTime() = 0;
};
```

Clock.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "IClock.h"

class Clock : public IClock
{
public:
    Clock();
    virtual ~Clock();
    void ClockUpdate();
    virtual void OnClockTime();

private:
    float elapsed_time;
};
```

Clock.cpp:

```
#include "Clock.h"

Clock::Clock()
    : elapsed_time(0.0f)
{
}

Clock::~Clock()
{
}

void Clock::ClockUpdate()
{
    elapsed_time += 0.0000001f; // small ticks for testing
    if (elapsed_time >= 1.0f) {
        OnClockTime();
        elapsed_time -= 1.0f;
    }
}
void Clock::OnClockTime()
{}
```

ApplicationBase.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Clock.h"

class ApplicationBase : public Clock
{
public:
    ApplicationBase();
    virtual ~ApplicationBase();

    virtual void Init(){}
    virtual void Run(){}

protected:
    bool app_run;
};
```

ApplicationBase.cpp:

```
#include "ApplicationBase.h"

ApplicationBase::ApplicationBase()
    : app_run(false)
{
}

ApplicationBase::~ApplicationBase()
{
}
```

DerivedApp.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "ApplicationBase.h"

class DerivedApp : public ApplicationBase
{
public:
    DerivedApp();
    virtual ~DerivedApp();

    virtual void Init() {}
    virtual void Run();

    //virtual void OnClockTime();
};
```

DerivedApp.cpp:

```
#include "DerivedApp.h"
#include <iostream>

DerivedApp::DerivedApp()
{
}

DerivedApp::~DerivedApp()
{
}

void DerivedApp::Run()
{
    app_run = true;
    while (app_run) {
        ClockUpdate();
    }
}

//void DerivedApp::OnClockTime()
//{
//  static int counts(0);
//  std::cout << "Tick..." << std::endl;
//  counts++;
//  if (counts >= 10)
//      app_run = false;
//}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "DerivedApp.h"

class App : public DerivedApp
{
public:
    App(){}
    ~App(){}
};

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    App *app = new App();
    app->Init();
    app->Run();
    delete app;
}
```

Thanks to those who requested a minimal working example, I built it and it works exactly as I had hoped. The complier will complain about no instantiation of the ABC in the App class. If I remove the comments from DerivedApp::OnClockTime() it compiles and runs the way I wish. Obviously my actual code is not following this model as I thought, so now I need to reexamine where I went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the program that compiles but then crashes, and show it to us?

Comment: The code you show _does_ define `OnTimeExpired`. It does not call the method, however. Do you have a minimal example that compiles but crashes?

Comment: Did you ever try to instantiate a `Application` object directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no keyword in C++ that forces a class to override some method. However, by making `OnTimeExpired()` pure virtual you're making `IClock` an abstract class. Any classes deriving from `IClock` that do not implement `OnTimeExpired()` will automatically become an abstract class too, thus not allowing you to create objects of these classes. This means that your code as-is is completely legal unless you try to make objects of these classes

Comment: "*There is no keyword in C++ that forces a class to override some method*" - not a specific keyword, no. But a pure virtual method accomplishes the same thing, and the compiler is *supposed* to fail to instantiate any class that has any pure methods that are not overidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AbstractBase {
public:
    virtual void someFunc() = 0; // Purely Virtual
};

class AbstractDerived : public AbstractBase {
public:
    void someOtherFunc();

    // Still abstract because the following is not declared-defined
    // void someFunc() override { ... }
};

class NonAbstractDerivedA : public AbstractBase { // Derived From Base
public:
    void someFunc() override { /* do this class's implementation*/ }
};

class NonAbstractDerivedB : public AbstractDerived { // Derived From AbstractDerived
public: 
    void someFunc() override { /* do this class's implementation*/ }
};
```

*uses:*

```
#include "above"

int main() {
    AbstractBase base; // compiler error

    AbstractDerived derived; // compiler error

    NonAbstractDerivedA derivedA; // should be okay

    NonAbstractDerivedB derivedB; // should be okay

    return 0;
}
```